# how can i select particular checkbox within datagrid itemrenderer in flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex3, air, desktop-application

I have button like random click ,if i click this button then will select 15 checkbox within datagrid itemrenderer checkbox But i can't access the checkbox ? please refer me ? How can access the checkbox ?

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="1"  rendererIsEditor="true" editorDataField="selected">
     <mx:itemRenderer> 
<mx:Component> 
<mx:CheckBox textAlign="center" click="{data.check1 = (data.check1 != 'true') ? 'true' : 'false'};outerDocument.toggleCheckbox(data);outerDocument.calcValues();" dataChange="this.selected=outerDocument.validateCheckbox(data)" themeColor="#ffff00" fillAlphas="[1, 1, 0.75, 0.65]" fillColors="[#f7f7d3, #ffffff, #ff9900, #ffff00]" /> 
     </mx:Component>
     </mx:itemRenderer>
     </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code:
**Data.as**

```
package
{
    public class Data
    {
        [Bindable]
        public var name:String;

        [Bindable]
        public var checked:Boolean;
        public function Data(name:String, checked:Boolean)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.checked = checked;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical"
    xmlns:local="*" creationComplete="create();">
    <mx:Button label="Randomize" click="randomize()"/>
    <mx:Button label="Trace selected indices" click="traceValues()"/>
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%" rowCount="5" 
        dataProvider="{dp}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Checked" dataField="checked">
              <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                  <mx:CheckBox selected="{data.checked}" 
                    change="{data.checked = this.selected;}/>
                </mx:Component>
              </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            public var dp:ArrayCollection;
            public function create():void
            {
                var array:Array = [];
                for(var i:Number = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    array.push(new Data("The Name", false));
                dp = new ArrayCollection(array);
            }
            private function randomize():void
            {
              var selectedNumbers:Array = [];
              var randomNumber:Number;
              for(var i:Number = 0; i < 5; i++)
              {
                do
                  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
                while(selectedNumbers.indexOf(randomNumber) != -1);
                dp.getItemAt(randomNumber).checked = !dp.getItemAt(randomNumber).checked;
                selectedNumbers.push(randomNumber);
              }
            }
            private function traceValues():void
            {
              for(var i:Number = 0; i < 20; i++)
              {
                if(dp.getItemAt(i).checked)
                  trace(i);
              }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Amarghosh thank you thank you so .
 i am working lot of time for this but you can do within 10 min . What!!!! a talent you are .

Answer (score 0):

Call `outerDocument.someMethod(this)` from the check box's change event handler. This way, the `someMethod(checkBox:CheckBox)` can access the check box.

It would be easier to read your code if you break it to different lines rather than hiding everything at the far right end.

UPDATE:

```
<!-- this is your DataGridColumn's itemRenderer -->
<mx:itemRenderer>  
  <mx:Component>
    <mx:CheckBox textAlign="center" selected="{data.checked}"/>
  <mx:Component>
<mx:itemRenderer>
```

Add this to the random button's click handler:

```
var selectedNumbers:Array = [];
var randomNumber:Number;
for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  do
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
  while(selectedNumbers.indexOf(randomNumber) != -1);
  //dp is the data provider of the data grid
  dp.getItemAt(randomNumber).checked = true;
  selectedNumbers.push(randomNumber);
}
```

Comment: ok thank you for your value infromation Amarghosh .
But i want How can i select 15 checkbox when the button(btn Name is Random)click .

Comment: updated the post to select 15 random check boxes in the data grid. btw, why do you wanna do this?

Comment: user want to select randomly 15 checkbox so i add button this button .i tried but shows error like checked not defult value so i add  //calamount is datagrid name
for each (var item:Object in calamount.dataProvider) {
item.checked = true;
} if i run i got
display tag like <checked>true</checked>

Comment: multiple lines of code in a comment is hard to read. Updating the question with this code would make it easier.

Comment: so after that i add like for(i = 0; i < 15; i++)
 { calamount.dataProvider[i].check1=true; 
}

what can i do it ? Why Why cant select checkbox in datagrid ?

Comment: Make sure that the `check1` property is `[Bindable]`. Then the check box will be selected automatically.

Comment: NO . How can i set check1 property is [Bindable] .

here i used
<mx:CheckBox click="{data.check1 = (data.check1 != 'true') ? 'true' : 'false'};outerDocument.toggleCheckbox(data);outerDocument.calcValues();" dataChange="this.selected=outerDocument.validateCheckbox(data)"()